# Codeigniter active query error

Tags: codeigniter

Here is my query

```
$this->db->select('amount AS SavingAmount');
    $query  = $this->db->get_where('cashman_trial_balance',array('category_id'=>'176','clientId'=>$user['UserID'],'year'=>$year));
```

On checking in browser its generating this query below

```
SELECT *, *, `amount` AS SavingAmount FROM (`cashman_trial_balance`) WHERE `category_id` = '176' AND `clientId` = '122' AND `year` = '2015/2016'
```

I dont know from where the two stars coming from?

Controller code

```
$som_var = $this->client->statistics();
```

Model code

```
function statistics() 
{ 
/* Some other queries */ 
$b = $this->get_balances(); 
} 
function get_balances() 
{ 
$this->db->select('amount AS SavingAmount'); 
$query = $this->db->get_where('cashman_trial_balance',array('category_id'=>'176','clientI‌​d'=>$user['UserID'],'year'=>$year)); 
return $query->result(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
      $query = $this->db->query("SELECT amount AS SavingAmount FROM table_name WHERE category_id = '176' 
      AND clientId = '$user['UserID']' AND 'year'= '$year') ");
      $result = $query->result_array();
      return $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the simple way

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT amount AS SavingAmount FROM cashman_trial_balance WHERE category_id = '176' AND clientId=$user['UserID'] AND year=$year");
```