# How to use OR_Where with AND condition in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-query-builder

I am using CodeIgniter. I need to understand how `where` and `or_where` condition working in codeigniter query builder.

I need an output like `where a="" AND b="" AND c="" OR d="" AND e=""`

so I tried an associative array.

```
$where= array('a'=>$firstname,'b'=>$lastname,'c'=>1);
$or_where= array('d' =>$customer_mobile,'e'=>1);
```

But I am getting the output
`where a="" AND b="" AND c="" OR d="" OR e=""`

Would you help in out in this?

Yes, My question is different. I asked about the `or_where` condition. Please check my expect output and getting output. And the duplicate question is different.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grouping WHERE clauses in Codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470267/grouping-where-clauses-in-codeigniter)

Comment: @iainn, Then what is the answer for this?

Comment: I think you haven't notice that or_where condition. Kindly check it again. I have multiple condition

Comment: use normal `query()`. I don't think, this can achievable. Even with Laravel i got same kind issue

Comment: @AbdullaNilam, Thanks for the reply, Normal query means I have to use $or_where=('d'="" AND 'e'="");  something like this?

Comment: use normal SQL and add to this  `$this->db->query("SELECT .....");` check https://stackoverflow.com/a/31285071/4595675

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

Use `query grouping` like this : change your `table name` and `variables` according to you

```
$firstname = 'a';
$lastname = 'b';
$customer_mobile = 'd';
$this->db->select('*')->from('users')
        ->group_start()
                ->where('a', $firstname)
                ->where('b', $lastname)
                ->where('c', '1')
                ->or_group_start()
                        ->where('d', $customer_mobile)
                        ->where('e', '1')
                ->group_end()
        ->group_end()
->get();
echo $this->db->last_query();
```

The output will be like this :

```
SELECT * FROM `users` 
WHERE ( `a` = 'a' AND `b` = 'b' AND `c` = '1'
OR ( `d` = 'd' AND `e` = '1' ) )
```

For more : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#query-grouping

Comment: Thanks for reply, @pradeep, give me time to implement this

Comment: If I have to use join ->join('membership_details', 'members.member_id = membership_details.member_id', 'Left');  then I have to add before group_start ?

Comment: pleasure is mine , happy coding